# IIS url rewrite rule for querystring params

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have url similar to this:
https://www.example.com/en-us/searchresults.aspx?Search=seachterm

Notice the parameter Search starts in uppercase.

How can I create a rewrite rule that keeps everything the same but just changes **Search** to **search** (all lowercase) ?

The url might contain other parameters and the path before the Search might also be different from the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following rule:

```
<rule name="UrlWithQueryStringToLowercase" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />                        
      <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
          <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)" />
          <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="([A-Z]+)" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}?{ToLower:{C:1}}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```